# Break row of list items across multiple rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating an inline unordered list but the items just keep on iterating straight horizontally.

What I want is to create three items inline then the next three items below.

The problem with my creation is that it keeps iterating horizontally in one line.

```css
.product {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
.product_area {
  display: inline;
}
.product_ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="product_area">
  <ul class="product_ul">
      <li><div class="product"></div></li>
      <li><div class="product"></div></li>
      <li><div class="product"></div></li>
      <li><div class="product"></div></li>
      <li><div class="product"></div></li>
      <li><div class="product"></div></li>
      <li><div class="product"></div></li>
      <li><div class="product"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29qvekLz/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-wrap: nowrap`. This means that flex items are forced to stay on a single line. That's the main problem you're having.

You can override the default with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```css
.product_ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  flex: 0 0 30%; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product_area">
  <ul class="product_ul">
    <li><div class="product"></div></li>
    <li><div class="product"></div></li>
    <li><div class="product"></div></li>
    <li><div class="product"></div></li>
    <li><div class="product"></div></li>
    <li><div class="product"></div></li>
    <li><div class="product"></div></li>
    <li><div class="product"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```